# Display images based on Textbox input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to display a number of images in my view based on a `TextBox` input.

I have this `Controller`:

```
public ActionResult GetProducts(long id, Search obj)
{
    GetSearchByDropdowns();
    using (ThBEntities1 db = new ThBEntities1())
    {
        if (id == null) {
            return View("Index");
        }

        byte[] image = db.Searches.Where(x => x.SearchTextBox == x.Product).SingleOrDefault().producturl;
        var stream = new MemoryStream(image.ToArray());
        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/jpeg");
    }
    return View("~/Views/Search/Index.cshtml", obj);
}
```

And in my view

```
if (Model.producturl != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)--I only have 6 records
    {
        <img src='@Url.Action("GetProducts", "Search", new{ id = i })' />
    }
}
```

And my Model

```
public partial class Search
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public byte[] producturl { get; set; }
}
```

I receive this error:

> ```
>     The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
> non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method
> 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetProducts(Int64, ThunderBird.Search)'
> in 'ThunderBird.Controllers.SearchController'. An optional parameter
>  must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an
>  optional parameter.
> ```

I know it comes from `GetProducts(long id, Search obj)` , but how can I pass the model from view as a parameter?

Comment: Did you check what is the URL format rendered in browser? Is it binding proper value for `i` ?

Comment: @SivaGopal , what do you mean as URL format? The value from `i` I pass it as parameter for an ID in DataBase.

Comment: Is that `Model.producturl` if-condition the only one part where request to `GetProducts` method available? Since `int` may automatically fits to `long`, `@Url.Action` shouldn't be the issue. Also check requested image URL format in Network tab on developer console.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto , yes the only part where GetProduct is available, after I press the button Search it goes right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I did it like this:

```
Controller
      public ActionResult GetProducts(Search obj)
            {
                GetSearchByDropdowns();

                Search c = null;
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-QR66UQL;Initial Catalog=ThB;Integrated Security=True";
                conn.Open();
                using (conn)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ProductImage from Search where Product='" + obj.SearchTextBox + "'");
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        c = new Search();
                        c.ImagePath = reader["ProductImage"].ToString();
                        obj.S.Add(c);
                    }
                    return View("~/Views/Search/Index.cshtml", obj);
                }
            }

View
 if (Model.S != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.S)
        {
            <img src='@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)' alt="Image" />
        }
    }
```

Mybe not the ideal solution, but it works for me as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you are creating src of img by this way

```
<img src='@Url.Action("GetProducts", "Search", new{ id = i })' />
```

you must not see this error of paramter dictionary, in that case your image will not render on browser.

I think you are hitting this method from some other source like button or form.